# Power analysis in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to get power consumption results for my design which is written in VHDL using value change dump (VCD) file. I tried Xilinx power tool and Cadence power tools. What I observe is that if I simulate it for longer time (larger VCD file) I have more power consumption. If I simulate it for shorter time (smaller VCD file ), I get less power consumption.

Suppose the complete operation for the design only takes 10 ns, which kind of measurement is more accurate and why? Should I only simulate it for 10 ns or should I simulate it for like 1 ms to get the power results?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to estimate power is to get the [power calculation tool](http://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/power/xpe.html) from the manufacturer and use that. The usually need figures from your synthesis, like luts and flipflops and the clock speed they are running at (this is a simple explanation). If you are worried about power then give yourself some margin and use the tool to give you maximum power figures for the worst-case usage scenario, that will get you in the ballpark.